# collectd plugin in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm trying to install the [GenericJMX Plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aGenericJMX) in NetBeans 6.9. I'm a newbie and I simply can't understand how to proceed with it. This may seem too generic a question but can someone please tell me how to go about it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin in question in specifically for the [collectd](http://collectd.org/) daemon.  It cannot be used in the NetBeans IDE.

If you would like to monitor a running JVM instance have a look at [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) specifically and [JMX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html) in general.

There is also a [JMX and JConsole Plugin](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/jmx-getstart.html) for NetBeans which help you build management into your application, among other things, but If you just want to monitor a running application have a look at the JConsole link above.

**Edit:**
The collectd-java plugin is a plugin for the collectd daemon.  It embeds a JVM into collectd and provides access to collectd's API.  See [collectd-java](http://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-java.5.shtml) documentation for more info.

So, my understanding of this is that collectd has a plugin named collectd-java and when this plugin is enabled you can use the GenericJMX Plugin to monitor all JVM processes.  You can also use this plugin to send messages/statistics to the collectd daemon from your applications.  For example, the documentation states:

> Advanced Java processes can use the JMX interface to provide performance information themselves. The Apache Tomcat application server, for example, provides information on the number of requests processed, the number of bytes sent, processing time, and thread counts.

If you would like to do something similar to the above, you will need to include the java bindings in your project which in source form are located [collectd-src]/bindings/java.  If you would just like to monitor your JVM instances, it seems to me that you can just configure collectd to do this according to the documentation on the [GenericJMX Plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aGenericJMX) page under the Synopsis heading.

The library libvirt plugin is for monitoring Virtual Machines such as the [Xen hypervisor](http://xen.org/).  While the JVM is a "Virtual Machine" it is not the same as the Virtual Machines that this plugin is targeting.  From the documentation for libvirt:

> The used libvirt library provides abstracted access to a number of virtualization techniques. At the moment (April 2010), the Xen, Qemu and KVM backends are able to provide the collected statistics.

I didn't find any references to the libvirt plugin from the Java plugin.

Comment: @Jonathon Spooner: Thanks. I'm using collectd along with libvirt so that I can monitor my VMs. Any pointers on that?

Comment: @PRamesh Could you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to analyse CPU, Network and Memory utilisation of the Virtual machines running on the Physical machines. Looking at the libvirt website for monitoring tools, I found out that collectd has a Java plugin which uses Libvirt to do the monitoring. I'm trying to integrate the plugin with an application I've already developed in java. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PRamesh see my edit for my findings.  I have never used collectd before but it seems that in order to monitor JVMs you only need to configure the GenericJMX Plugin.

Comment: I was talking about http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:libvirt . From the description given, doesn't it imply that libvirt+collectd will help us monitor the VMs using Libvirt? Thanks

Comment: @PRamesh Yes libvirt will help you monitor VMs.  However, to monitor the JVM you will need to use the collectd-java plugin.

Comment: I don't want to monitor the JVM. Monitoring VMs would do. How can I do it?

Comment: @PRamesh Your question was somewhat misleading.  I can only suggest that you study the documentation for libvirt http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:libvirt